# Official Stack Exchange Android App

Tags: app, android

### Screenshots

[image: main feed] [image: question listing] [image: answers]

### About

Stack Exchange is a network of 100+ question and answer communities on everything from software programming to cooking, photography, and gaming. With this app you can:

- Track all your interests in one place with the new combined feed view
- Get instant notifications when you receive an answer or comment
- Search for questions, or browse by tag
- Ask, answer, comment and vote on questions

This is the official app for all Stack Exchange sites, including Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Arqade.

New to Stack Exchange? Here’s how it works:

- Anybody can ask or answer a question
- The best answers are voted to the top
- You earn reputation points for every vote you receive
- Unlock privileges as you earn reputation, like the ability to comment or vote
- The community is run by you: moderators are elected, and top users have access to special tools to help moderate

#### License

Free [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) app

#### Download

You can download the app from Android Market as "Stack Exchange" or by following the link below
[Google Play download link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).

#### Platform

Currently released for Android version 4.1 and up.

### Contact

Developed by: Stack Exchange

Comment: There will be an official app? Spiffy (and I'm glad you snagged app id 4240 for this before somebody else took it). Here's to hoping it doesn't [keep mods in the dark](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/111212/moderator-flag-notifications-should-reach-mobile).

Comment: Related: [Help us test the Alpha version of our Android App](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/190200)

Comment: Interesting; there's now a link to this page when a user makes a comment using the SO app.

Comment: Is it an open source app? and if so, is the source code on Github?

Comment: Where can we submit bugs for this app?

Comment: @Montag451 On MSE under the bug and android-app tags

Comment: @Geoff I added a screenshot from the Google Play listing to the post... is that all right or should there be different images for this post? :)

Comment: The app has been removed from Google Play -- why?

Comment: As of 2021 - the [official application is no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348076/135565)